# bootstrap divs not stacking properly in mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I've got 2 issues I would like assistance with if possible.

1. I'm using bootstrap to create a responsive website for a friend of mine. I'm new to it all and as I've been using bootstrap, I see it automatically stacks divs depending on screen size (I.E. in mobile view). Issue I'm having is that for whatever reason bootstrap is stacking the last couple of divs on top of each other. I thought that I possible forgot to close out a tag but I've been scrutinizing the code and can't seem to find any open tags. I've also removed any of my custom CSS to see if that was causing the issue and that also didn't help. Any ideas guys?
2. I'm also using backstretch to add an image to the background of the first div, as well as for the slideshow on the page and for whatever reason it is resizing images too large for the containers they are in, resulting in images that are cut off. Any assistance in getting this properly formatted?

I'm sure the formatting issue is something silly I missed, any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

http://evlands.com/EV.html

thats the link to the site. everything is tentative and we're waiting on some pro pics of his work. Any suggestions to the site are also appreciated

Comment: share some code. the link is taking time to open..

Comment: Like what developemator mentioned, you are overriding the framework row classes with width and height. Bootstrap is meant for responsive so there's no need to set a width and height for the divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the view source of the page and what I see is that you are having col class for md size in div - example class="col-md-4", this will only work for medium size devices. If you make the browser size small - you need to add class for small size devices in the div as well. Example class" col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" - you need decide on the column size for other devices - small screen and x-small, so that when you make the page small the col-sm-4 / col-xs-4 will be used - see below example

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">          
  <p></p>
</div>
```

For more information on this please check this link [on grid and media queries](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)
hope this helps.

Comment: thank you sir this did the job. silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

At first look, you are overriding the framework row classes with width and height.

Try and keep with rows stand alone and if you do use classes for the row col structure make it only for styling and the inner div contents.

Once you start fighting with the built in grid it's can go downhill fast.

Comment: Here's a good start.  Not sure if backstretch is a good idea. I would use cycle2 if you want a carousel.

Comment: backstretch hasn't given me issues aside from this 1. I've tried cycle2 before and didn't really get my attention. I'll try it again on another project. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: What I do not like about it is all the images are loaded via the js with it, the initial images should come in on its own payload or with the css to prevent and lazy load below the fold images to reduce/eliminate FOUC.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all your code, judging from your site it looks like you have some absolute divs that aren't taking up the space you're hoping they will when the page resizes.

If you'd like to fix some of these things yourself without relying on bootstrap. Look into [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). You can specify certain properties at certain screen sizes